# extra logs written when posting messages to ibm mq

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a job that posts messages onto IBM MQ.
I have configured my logs to write to a file and not console.
yet when I run this job everytime I see a large amount of logs on the console like this

I have just changed ips and company name in the logs but 
what is the source of this 
why does it come up
and how do I stop this ?

All my messages get posted successfully so from an end user perspective the job is working fine however I'm not able to make out why this comes up on the console?

```
RcvThread: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection[qmid=CANNED_DATA,fap=10,peer=naumib3.mydomain.net/112.999.138.25,localport=56857,ssl=SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA,peerDN="CN=ibmwebspheremqnaumib3, OU=For Intranet Use Only, OU=For Intranet Use Only, O=My Company, L=New York, ST=New York, C=US",issuerDN="CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US"], READ: SSLv3 Application Data, length = 72
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Application Data, length = 68
[Raw write]: length = 73
0000: 17 03 00 00 44 54 53 48   43 00 00 00 30 01 0C 30  ....DTSHC...0..0
0010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 01 11 03 33 00  ..............3.
0020: 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  ................
0030: 00 00 00 00 00 41 69 2A   27 7E EB 3A 9B 47 4A 02  .....Ai*'..:.GJ.RcvThread: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection[qmid=CANNED_DATA,fap=10,peer=naumib3.mydomain.net/112.999.138.25,localport=56857,ssl=SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA,peerDN="CN=ibmwebspheremqnaumib3, OU=For Intranet Use Only, OU=For Intranet Use Only, O=My Company, L=New York, ST=New York, C=US",issuerDN="CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US"], received EOFException: ignored
RcvThread: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection[qmid=CANNED_DATA,fap=10,peer=naumib3.mydomain.net/112.999.138.25,localport=56857,ssl=SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA,peerDN="CN=ibmwebspheremqnaumib3, OU=For Intranet Use Only, OU=For Intranet Use Only, O=My Company, L=New York, ST=New York, C=US",issuerDN="CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US"], called closeInternal(false)
RcvThread: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection[qmid=CANNED_DATA,fap=10,peer=naumib3.mydomain.net/112.999.138.25,localport=56857,ssl=SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA,peerDN="CN=ibmwebspheremqnaumib3, OU=For Intranet Use Only, OU=For Intranet Use Only, O=My Company, L=New York, ST=New York, C=US",issuerDN="CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US"], SEND SSLv3 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
```

Answer (score 0):

The output looks like it might be from some type of debug or diagnostic patch that might be applied to the MQ JMS/Java client you have installed. The RcvThread is the thread used internally to listen on the TCP socket for data from the QM. Do you know of a patch that might be applied to help with TCP connection issues in the past?

You might want to look at the com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar that is contained in the MQ client you are using to see if there is a difference in the timestamp or anything noted in the manifest file within the jar file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous answere that is not normally the format of any logs that get written by the JMS Client code.  Under normal circumstances the only time that logs are written to stdout in two cases:

One the JMS Client log file controlled by

```
# Name(s) of the log file(s)
# Can be 
#    * a single pathname 
#    * a comma-separated list of pathnames (all data is logged to all files) 
# Each pathname can be 
#    * absolute or relative pathname
#    * "stderr" or "System.err" to represent the standard error stream
#    * "stdout" or "System.out" to represent the standard output stream 
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.outputName=mqjms.log
```

And what is called JMS Startup trace - a very early tracing system normally only used on request of IBM Service. (this is documented also in the jms.config file).